# fail getting value of get/set using an object to it's class

Tags: c#, multithreading, class

I'll explain but codes can explain it way better than me.

I'm trying to get value of 2 variables
I create a new object at it's class and use its members which I set their values from packet.
Whenever I try to access them I find them zeros which kind of doesn't make sense to me.
Here is the important part of the code that is related to the problem

```
public class PacketHandler
    {
.
. dots means unrelated long code
.
public PacketHandler()
        {
        }
        public ushort actualX { get; set; }
        public ushort actualY { get; set; }
.
.
.
case 10010:
                            {
                                if (BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 8) == 1002)
                                {
                                    actualX = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 24);
                                    actualY = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 26);
                                }
                                break;
```

and here is the other class I'm trying to get the value at

```
public class ClientBase
{
    GameUser role2;
    PacketHandler ph = new PacketHandler(); <<<<<<<<
    public ClientBase(GameUser role)
    {
        role2 = role;
        Thread T = new Thread(HuntThread) { Name = "Hunt Thread" };
        T.Start(this);
        Console.WriteLine("with name : " +T.Name +  " with execution context : "+T.ExecutionContext +" with state : "+ T.IsAlive + " with id : " + T.ManagedThreadId);
       T.Join();
    }
    Monster GetNextkill()
    {
        Monster CurrentTarget = null;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, Monster> Pair in Dictionary.Clone(Dictionary.Monsters))
        {

                CurrentTarget = Pair.Value;
        }
        return CurrentTarget;
    }
    public void HuntThread(object Sender)
    {
        try
        {
            ClientBase Client = Sender as ClientBase;
            while (true)
            {
                Monster Target = GetNextkill();
                if (Target != null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    ProxyParadise.Network.Packets.PacketStructure ps = new ProxyParadise.Network.Packets.PacketStructure();

                    ps.__Packet10010(Target.X, Target.Y, role2, "normal", "server", ph.actualX, ph.actualY); <<<<< i get zeros at the ph.actualX/Y
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    ps.__Packet10010(Target.X, Target.Y, role2, "sdasdsa", "client", role2.X, role2.Y);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    ps.__Packet1022NONEXP(Target.UID, Target.X , Target.Y, role2);
                    Dictionary.Monsters.SafeRemove(Target.UID);
```

please forgive me if I sound stupid, and to make it more clear ,I want a proper way of transferring data through classes at a new thread.
Please try to apply it to this example for better understanding.
have a wonderful day

Comment: Please convert this into a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem. It's unclear to me at the moment.

Comment: Please add a language tag to this.